# How can I differentiate directory text color when using powerlevel10k?

Tags: zsh, iterm2

I am using Zsh and with powerlevel10k in Iterm2. but I would like to differentiate directory and file when you type `ls` . How can I achieve this?

[image: ,]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-G` tag.
you can make an alias to always have it:

In your profile conf add:

`alias ls='ls -G'`